# Setting InheritanceFlags vs PropagationFlags in Powershell

Tags: powershell, inheritance, propagation

I'm trying to find the right combination of the InheritanceFlags and PropagationFlags so that my new folder will not inherit the folder's permissions before it, but will propagate the rights to the folders/files contained in the new folder... I tried swapping the two from what I have below, but that only gave the new folder the same permissions as the one above it and didn't apply my new groups...

How do I set the flags correctly to only apply the permissions to all files/folders below this folder and not pull from the parent folder?

I found [this table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Envcj0iYmYHyB_xA4aFe8VwlpReQdP2pr3rl-HjgfcU/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&output=html), but it doesn't seem to do what I'm wanting...

```
function New-Ace {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [Security.Principal.NTAccount]$Account,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=1)]
    [Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]$Permissions = 'ReadAndExecute',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)]
    [Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]$InheritanceFlags = 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=3)]
    [Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]$PropagationFlags = 'None',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=4)]
    [Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]$Type = 'Allow'
  )

  New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
    $Account, $Permissions, $InheritanceFlags, $PropagationFlags, $Type
  )
}

$domain = 'TestDomain'

$administrators = ([wmi]"Win32_Sid.Sid='S-1-5-32-544'").AccountName

$acl = Get-Acl $path

$administrators, "$domain\Domain Admins" | ForEach-Object {
  $acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace $_ 'FullControl'))
}
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace $ADNameRW 'Modify'))
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Ace $ADNameRO 'ReadAndExecute'))

Set-Acl $path $acl
```

Comment: [`SetAccessRuleProtection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection.aspx)?

Comment: Can you explain a little more? The link you sent me is a .net coding page and this is in PowerShell. I'm pretty new to PowerShell so that page didn't really help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calling `$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $false)` should prevent that directory or file from inheriting permissions from its parent directory, with the second parameter specifying that the previously-inherited permissions should be removed.  Enabling protection = disabling inheritance.

In your `New-Ace` function, [`InheritanceFlags`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.accesscontrol.authorizationrule.inheritanceflags.aspx) specifies to which type of child object (files, directories, or both) the permissions can apply, and [`PropagationFlags`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.accesscontrol.authorizationrule.propagationflags.aspx) controls whether the permissions apply to this object and/or only immediate children.  Neither of these properties affects how this file or directory inherits from its parent.

By the way, PowerShell is built on .NET so the same classes, methods, etc. are available to you, and in some instances the only way to accomplish something that isn't covered by a cmdlet.

Comment: I've been pulling my hair out trying to understand how Inheritance and Propagation applied to the folder I was creating. Thank you!